# How to create a dynamic PivotItems ShowDetail = True for PivotFields("Month")?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Based on the screenshot, I would like to expand the selection of the month, only for the current month:

[image]

Here is the code, which is static as I manually adjust based on the current month:

```
Workbooks("NameOfWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets("NameOfWorksheet").PivotTables("PivotTableName").PivotFields("Month").PivotItems("Jan").ShowDetail = False

Workbooks("NameOfWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets("NameOfWorksheet").PivotTables("PivotTableName").PivotFields("Month").PivotItems("Feb").ShowDetail = False

Workbooks("NameOfWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets("NameOfWorksheet").PivotTables("PivotTableName").PivotFields("Month").PivotItems("Mar").ShowDetail = False

Workbooks("NameOfWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets("NameOfWorksheet").PivotTables("PivotTableName").PivotFields("Month").PivotItems("Apr").ShowDetail = False

Workbooks("NameOfWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets("NameOfWorksheet").PivotTables("PivotTableName").PivotFields("Month").PivotItems("May").ShowDetail = False

Workbooks("NameOfWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets("NameOfWorksheet").PivotTables("PivotTableName").PivotFields("Month").PivotItems("Jun").ShowDetail = False

Workbooks("NameOfWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets("NameOfWorksheet").PivotTables("PivotTableName").PivotFields("Month").PivotItems("Jul").ShowDetail = False

Workbooks("NameOfWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets("NameOfWorksheet").PivotTables("PivotTableName").PivotFields("Month").PivotItems("Aug").ShowDetail = True
```

Since the current month is still August, there are no PivotItems("Sep"), PivotItems("Oct"), etc in the Pivot Table.

**Question: How to create a dynamic PivotItems ShowDetail = True for PivotFields("Month") based on the current month?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to loop through and check the names versus the current month. Something like this:

```
    For Each m In Sheets("NameOfWorksheet").PivotTables("PivotTableName").PivotFields("Month").PivotItems
        If m.Value = Format(Now(), "MMM") Then
            m.ShowDetail = True
        Else
            m.ShowDetail = False
        End If
    Next m
```

Note, the way things are set up in your picture there is no reference to the year. So you may have issues with data integrity if your data covers month than 12 months.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! It worked as intended! For this report, it is capped to the same year hence the data will not go beyond 12 months